# Drupal 8 batch process in form with ajax submit button

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

How can I run Drupal 8 batch process in Drupal form triggered by ajax submit button?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would likely want to run your batch via [`batch_set`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21form.inc/function/batch_set/8.7.x) in the `::formSubmit` method, assuming it's a custom form. Technically I don't think you should care if its from AJAX or not but you could check the request type in there as well if it matters. You can actually see an example of this in the `batch_example` module's [`BatchExampleForm::submitForm`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/examples/blob/8.x-1.x/batch_example/src/Form/BatchExampleForm.php) method.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/317582/how-to-run-batch-without-redirection or https://github.com/poojasharma48/batch_example_without_redirect